# webbrowser URL from listview

Tags: c#

i have favorites in my c# webbrowser and i try to change the url when the form is closing
my code:

```
    private void Favorites_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Xml.XmlTextWriter writer = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\Favorites.xml", null);

        writer.WriteStartElement("Favorites");
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Item");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("url", listView1.Items[i].Text);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

How do i change the url when the form is closing?

Comment: where do you want to change the url ?

Comment: @AjayKelkar f1.web.Url = new Uri(???);

Comment: You have for loop on list view items , which one you want to set to f1.web.url , whichever , you put one property in you form class, set in while closing and use it outside

Comment: @AjayKelkar what you mean?

Comment: Json works a lot better for things like this. I actually just wrote a "Favorites" JSON class recently and can help you out.